# Can't Call ScriptAlias Site Within Perl Script Within Apache

Tags: apache, perl, cgi

I'm running an Apache 2.4 server.  I have the following script:

```
  1 #!/usr/bin/perl
  2 
  3 use strict;
  4 use warnings;
  5 use Getopt::Std;
  6 
  7 my $build = `curl -s https://myserver.myurl.com/mydir/myscript.pl`;
  8 print "$build\n";
```

This script lives on the Apache server.  If I run this script on the apache server, it doesn't work.  I get back nothing.

If I run this script locally, it works as expected.  It executes my script.pl on the apache server and I get back the correct data.

What could I possible be doing wrong here?  Any information that would help me to debug this is encouraged.

Here is my configuration settings for this directory in my apache config file:

```
ScriptAlias /mydir/ /srv/mydir/
<Directory /srv/mydir/>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None

    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: You probably don't have curl installed on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, shortly after I posted this question, I figured out the reason.

So if I change my curl command syntax to:

```
my $build = `curl -v https://myserver.myurl.com/mydir/myscript.pl`;
```

I am able to see the verbose output.  The output had this embedded in it:

```
* server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:05 --:--:--     0
* Closing connection 0
curl: (60) server certificate verification failed.
```

I am able to get it to work by bypassing this certificate verification by modifying my curl command syntax to this:

```
my $build = `curl -k https://myserver.myurl.com/mydir/myscript.pl`;
```

The flag **-k** is an alias for **--insecure**.  Basically bypasses the certificate verification.

The proper way though will be for me to figure out why the certificate is not installed and install it myself.